# Run git command to save output but consume STDERR too

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

I've tried:

```
status=$(git status -s ./$name>&1)
status=$(git status -s ./$name >2 /dev/null >&1)
status=$(git status -s ./$name >2 /dev/null)
status=$(git status -s ./$name > /dev/null 2> &1)
```

etc, etc.
I need to get the response from the git status command, or an empty string but I NEVER want to see a "fatal: Not a git repository" message.

Comment: your problem is that you are using `>2` and not `2>` to redirect stderr to `/dev/null`: the latter works, the former does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is:

```
status=$(git status -s ./$name 2> /dev/null)
```

What happens when you use that that you do not like?